# Naudio spectrum always different

Tags: audio, naudio, analyzer, spectrum

Ok. So either there is something I don't grasp about audio signals in general, or there is something up there.
Problem: Every time audio sound is played, the spectrum displayed (in demo) ends differently.
Try1:
[drum snare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXdF1.png)

Try2:
[same drumsnare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFVMw.png)

Shouldn't they be identical? Is this concidered in the terms of error "same" spectrum? Or am I missing something?
I am working on an idea, where I need a thorough sound analysis, which includes FFT, therefore would need as precise data as I can get. Any insights?

Comment: Are these the spectrum of the *exact same file*, or are they spectrum of two recordings of the same drum? The variation between very similar sounds from an instrument can be huge.

Comment: Exact same file. P.S. I moved on to other tools.